# Navigational Timeout When obstacle is in front

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, turtlebot, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I just have one quick question. Let me start out with an example:

I have a turtlebot type robot that is navigating a office space. During office hours, there are a lot of people standing in the hallway. As the robot approaches the group of people standing, it ends the path planning because it says the path is blocked. The robot doesn't bother to wait for a bit until the people create a path for the robot to move in. This isn't a question of obstacle avoidance, this is a question of a navigational timeout.

How can i make it that the robot waits say, "15 seconds" before finally determining that the path is blocked?

Thanks!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10804/navigational-timeout-when-obstacle-is-in-front/) by [kakadinho2210](https://answers.ros.org/users/921/kakadinho2210/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a plan fails the [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation) falls back on recovery behaviors.

This would be good recovery behavior to add to the navigation stack.  [recovery behavior API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_core#RecoveryBehavior) There are several other behaviors implemented but not this one.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0